# Keep facebook in a single chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, facebook

If I log into facebook, even once the tab is closed, sites I visit know my real name (presumably through cookies). Is there a way to use Chrome to completely isolate a single tab for facebook, so that none of the other sessions I create on sites can use data from it? Obviously an incognito window would work, but I'd like the ability to save my login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services such as [Disconnect](http://disconnect.me) and others (such as DoNotTrackMe and Ghostery) can delete tracking cookies and prevent this behavior.

---

**UPDATE**: The Chromium Project was considering implementing isolated sites, but later decided not to. More details [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/isolated-sites).

Comment: DoNotTrackMe seems to do what I want :) Thanks!